# Code work with Postman but not at localhost Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, postman, html-framework-7

I have a code of ajax which is calling WCF service, When I call it through localhost it says `Failed to load resource:http://servicelink?order%5B0%5D%5BCoupanId%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5BDiscount%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5BEmailAddress%5D=em.com&order%5B0%5D%5ailtemName%5D=Sgfa+wraps&order%5B0%5D%5BItem_Id%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5BQty%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5Bprice%5D=5.5 the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)`
however it takes all parameters with it. When I put the same link as above showing in the snippet in Postman by changing to POST, it works fine. 
I have changed this to also POST at localhost issue still exist.

Comment: Its 405 response right. Have you given any authentication or tokens in your postman ?

Comment: yes its 405. `No Auth` with postman

Comment: checked the headers ?

Comment: @Rigin try the same link in postman without authentication, it works

Comment: where to check the headers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121308/discussion-between-rigin-and-qadeer-mangrio).

Comment: I think this may have something to do with CORS and the browers cross origin policy which Postman avoids.

Comment: @skribe there isn't any cors, cors are allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you change this : `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

i got response with this:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; 
$.ajax({ 
url: "http://service link", 
type: "POST", 
dataType: "json", 
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 

// data: { order: orderData }, 
success: function (response) { 
alert(response.OrderPlacementResult); 
// orderId = data; 
if (data != null) { 
orderStatus = "Order has been placed successfully."; 
} 
} 

});
```

try from ur side

Comment: got it buddy. Thankx

Comment: nice anyhow.  I lost you in chat